# Не правильно срабатывает условие (альтернативный синтаксис PHP)

Tags: php, if

Добрый вечер! У меня в $_SESSION['access_token'] лежит токен.
Есть след. кусок кода:

```
<body>
    <?php
        if (!isset($_SESSION['access_token']))
        echo 'токена нет';
    else
        echo 'токен есть';
    ?>
    <? if (!isset($_SESSION['access_token'])) : ?>
        <?php
        $vkApp = new VK\VK('60345451', '076Gvj7B35wZu454oO');
        $authorizeURL = $vkApp->getAuthorizeURL('groups', 'https://sfgsdfgt.ru/vkgrofdgsdfgupsup/app/auth.php');
        $authorizeURL = urldecode($authorizeURL);
        ?>
        <a href="<?= $authorizeURL ?>">Авторизация</a>
        <?php exit; ?>
    <? endif; ?>
</body>
```

На выходе я получаю: 'токен есть' (так и должно быть) и ссылку на авторизацию (а так быть не должно).
Получается обычное условие сработало как нужно (т.е. не сработало, пошло по ветке else), а второе сработало неправильно (его будто нет вовсе).
Самое интересное, что я если я запишу `<? if (isset($_SESSION['access_token'])) : ?>` результат будет такой же. Почему проскакивает мимо условия?

Comment: Это простите извращение а не код. У вас шортеги отключены ззамена `<?` на `<?php` поможет.

Comment: @Naumov а как было бы правильно? Если ужасно, то проясните, в чем беда. Когда уместно использовать альт. синтаксис, а когда нет?

Comment: Альтернативный синтаксис в шаблонах нормально но шорттеги вида `<? ?>` не работают по умолчанию, по этому начинающие и садяться в лужу ошибки нет но не работает

Comment: всё в одном стиле должно